# Angular JS ng-repeat works with plain text, not with tr

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularfire

I'm admittedly new to AngularJS, but I've run into an issue with AngularFire and AngularJS where my code works correctly when I leave my data as plain text (not in a table format), but when I throw table formatting around my data, it no longer pulls the data correctly.

Here's what I'm working with: http://plnkr.co/edit/q6fZGrh5FLDxuOK8tYRk?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put a `<div>` directly inside of a `<table>`.  They have to go inside of a `<td>`.  I was able to duplicate your original results inside the `<table>` by nesting the content in the following way:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div ng-repeat="first one">
                <div ng-repeat="second one">
                    <div ng-repeat="third one">
                        <div ng-repeat="fourth one">
                            <div ng-repeat="fifth one">
                                <div ng-repeat="sixth one">
                                    Content goes here.
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You may need to add additional formatting (like `<br />`) to get it looking exactly how you want it.